# How best to structure my code in R when doing a lot of data manipulation/cleaning?

Tags: r, code-cleanup

I had a general question regarding most efficient coding as a beginner - I have a very wide dataset (374 obs), on which I have to do several manipulations on. I'll mainly be using 'mutate' and 'unite' . My question is:

How I write the code now is that everytime I do something new (ie if I combine 6 columns into one), then I'll write a separate code for that and create a new dataframe.

Underneath there'll be another code for 'mutate' like if I have to create a new variable by summing two columns.

here's an example:

```
#1B. Combine location columns. 
combinedlocations <- rawdata1 %>% unite(location, locations1,locations2, locations3, na.rm = TRUE, 
remove=TRUE)
combinedlocations <- combinedlocations[-c(6:7)] #drop the unwanted columns

#2. Combine Sector together into one new column: Sector
#B. Combine columns, but override if Type.of.org = 'Independent Artist', where Sector = "Independent 
Artist"
Combinedsectors <- combinedlocations %>% unite(Sector, Sectors, na.rm=TRUE, remove=TRUE)  %>%
```

I basically create a new dataframe for each manipulation, using the one I just created.

Is this correct? This is how I learned to do it on SAS. OR, is it better to do it all in one dataframe (maybe rawdata2) and is there a way to combine all these codes together, using %>% ? (I'm still trying to learn how piping works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on the edge of "opinion-based", but it's a good question.  **tl;dr** it doesn't matter very much, it's mostly a matter of your preferred style.

- putting everything in one long pipe sequence (`a %>% b %>% c %>% d`) without intermediate assignments means you don't have as many intermediate objects cluttering your workspace; this means (1) you don't have to come up with names for them all (`data1`, `data2`, ...) and (2) you don't use up memory making lots of extra objects (this isn't a problem unless you're working with Big Data)

On the other hand,

- putting everything in one long pipe sequence can make it harder to debug, because it's harder to inspect intermediate results if something goes wrong; [this blog post](https://www.rostrum.blog/2019/04/07/fix-leaky-pipes/) lists a variety of packages/tools that are handy for debugging pipe sequences.

I tend to use piping sequences of about 5-6 lines. Your code in piped format would look something like this ...

```
#1B. Combine location columns. 
Combinedsectors <- (rawdata1 
   %>% unite(location, locations1,locations2, locations3, 
             na.rm = TRUE, remove=TRUE)
   %>% select(-(6:7)) 
#2. Combine Sector together into one new column: Sector
#B. Combine columns, but override if Type.of.org = 'Independent Artist', where Sector = "Independent Artist"
   %>% unite(Sector, Sectors, na.rm=TRUE, remove=TRUE)  
   %>%  ... <whatever>
)
```